# Raw Image not showing some objects in render texture Unity2d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a render texture that good showing me a copy of room prefab, but when i insert it to my Raw Image, i have all: Player, bullets, but not room
[render texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44202.png)
[no room in game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3rIM.png)

Idk variants to do this, maybe some layers are conflicted.
It's white color, maybe some mask conflict to show it